# sys.dm_pdw_nodes_exec_requests has null values

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

This applies to Azure Synapse Analytics, aka Azure SQL Data Warehouse

My goal is to join sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests to sys.dm_pdw_nodes_exec_query_stats.

The DMV sys.dm_pdw_nodes_exec_query_stats provides great detail on query execution per compute node. I'd like to join entries in this table to execution requests in sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests. The DMV sys.dm_pdw_nodes_exec_requests can connect these DMVs with its sql_handle, session_id, and pdw_node_id columns.

My query is

```
select *
from sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests er
inner join sys.dm_pdw_sql_requests sr
    on er.request_id = sr.request_id
inner join sys.dm_pdw_nodes_exec_requests ner
    on sr.spid = ner.session_id
    and ner.pdw_node_id = sr.pdw_node_id
inner join sys.dm_pdw_nodes_exec_query_stats neqs
    on neqs.sql_handle = ner.sql_handle
```

It is based off of: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/parallel-data-warehouse-pdw-tip-useful-appliance-queries

**Two problems cause this query to return nothing**

1. For rows of sr and ner which join together, ner.sql_handle is null or
   0x000...0 and it can't join to neqs.
2. For rows of ner and neqs which join together, ner.session_id has no
   matching spid in sr.

**If there is there a legitimate reason for my two problems, is there another way to join sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests to sys.dm_pdw_nodes_exec_query_stats?

**Is there a way I can fix the Null/invalid values in the DMVs?**